# How to preserve file-create-timestamp while copying files on OS X from command-line?

Tags: macos, finder, file-transfer, cp

On OS X when you a copy a file using Finder, the target file has the same creation and modification times as the source file.

However when you do so using `cp` in Terminal both creation and modification times of the target are set to the time of copying. `cp -p` preserves modification time but not creation time - it is set to the value of the modification time.

Any one know of a command line tool in macs to accomplish the same behavior like in Finder when copying files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `ditto(1)`.

Comment: As far as I know, "ditto" suffers from the same defect.

Comment: links for `ditto`: http://osxdaily.com/2014/06/11/use-ditto-copy-files-directories-mac-command-line/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/40974437/5411817